# Woo Commerce , how to edit checkout page

Tags: wordpress, checkout, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-subscriptions, divi-theme

I am trying to edit the Product and checkout Page on Woocommerce. WE have a Divi theme installed, but it doesn’t allow me to customize the product page. Does anyone know where I can find the files that generate the product page so I can edit them? For example, I want to remove the product image, and make it a 2 column layout instead of 1. I know PHP/HTML/JS/CSS so I can edit it once I find out where to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Divi has the Theme Builder which can definitely let you custom design a Product page: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/theme-releases/divi-4

Here are some examples:

```
https://www.elegantthemes.com/examples/product/divi-theme-builder-6/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/examples/product/divi-theme-builder-5/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/examples/product/divi-theme-builder-4/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/examples/product/divi-theme-builder-3/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/examples/product/divi-theme-builder-2/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/examples/product/divi-theme-builder-1/
```

Answer (score 0):

**In order to override the woocommerce templates you look for:**

- If there is not exist a `woocomerce folder` in your theme root folder then, add one and name it `woocommerce` like `YourTheme->woocommerce`
- Then in your `woocommerce` folder add a folder and name it `checkout`
- Go into your `wp-content->plugins->woocommerce->templates->checkout` and copy the
  files that you want to override in you `theme->woocommerce->checkout`
  folder
- In `wp-content->plugins->woocommerce->templates` you will also find the
  `content-product.php` & `content-single-product.php`. Copy both and add them to your `theme->woocommerce folder`.

You can then start editing the files you want to change

Comment: I am having the folders in my wordpress , but in checkout there are 3 divisions which are coming from 3 diff pages and i wanted to know how these 3 pages are included in the checkout page. So that it will be easy to reach my requirement. And thankyou for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the Child Theme.

Then, go to the WooCommerce folder of the Child Theme, here is the template hierarchy for the checkout page: https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

[www.YourWebsiteURL.com/woocommerce.5.9.0/woocommerce/templates/checkout/](http://www.YourWebsiteURL.com/woocommerce.5.9.0/woocommerce/templates/checkout/) Here you can access the checkout templates.

Let me know if that helps!